# Spelling: "You +1'd this"

Tags: verbs, orthography, apostrophe, simple-past

[image]

Can you please elaborate in detail as to why there is an *apostrophe **d*** after the *+1*?

Comment: It's hard to answer this since it is clearly not a grammatically correct english sentence. It's just a convenient abbreviation, and the apostrophe just makes it easier to read.

Comment: @Urbycoz: grammatically, the sentence is impeccable. We can talk about the various ways of spelling it out, but we won't find a grammar rule being broken here. "To plus-one" is a perfectly fine verb. English is flexible like that. And like any other perfectly fine verb, it is allowed to have a simple-past form.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道: But this question is about the abbreviation "+1", not the verb "plus-one" itself. Using the abbreviation in a sentence as above is not grammatically correct English. Also, are you sure "plus-one" is an acceptable verb? I can only find it listed as a noun: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plus-one?s=t

Comment: @Urbycoz wait a couple years and it will be in every dictionary, just like "to google" and "to facebook". And again, using numbers to spell words is not *grammatically* wrong. The grammar of a sentence does not change in the slightest if you replace "plus" with "+" or "you" with "u". Which is why we have textspeak. Or Morse code, for that matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clicking "+1" means you're adding yourself to the number of people who support or like this thing.

Clicking "+1" is an action, and *plus one* is being used as a verb for clicking it.

Usually the past tense of a verb such as *walk* is *walked*.

The past tense of performing this +1 action, could be spoken as "*plus one*-d", which has been written as *+1'd*.

The apostrophe is often used to denote the omission of something, or in this case to try to improve readability, and possibly an attempt to hide some of the uncertainty of how to properly make a symbol such as "+1" into the past tense.